# How can I formatMessage with a tags (links) using react-intl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I need to add links to the text I need translated. How can I formatMessages that have links?

Right now this is what I am trying to do:

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  copy: {
    id: 'checkout.OrderReview.copy',
    description: 'Label for add card button',
    defaultMessage: 'By clicking the "Place Order" button, you confirm that you have read, understood, and accept our {termsAndConditionsLink}, {returnPolicyLink}, and {privacyPolicyLink}.',
  },
  termsAndConditions: {
    id: 'checkout.OrderReview.termsAndConditions',
    description: 'Label for terms and conditions link',
    defaultMessage: 'Terms and Conditions',
  },
  returnPolicy: {
    id: 'checkout.OrderReview.returnPolicy',
    description: 'Label for return policy link',
    defaultMessage: 'Return Policy',
  },
  privacyPolicy: {
    id: 'checkout.OrderReview.privacyPolicy',
    description: 'Label for privacy policy link',
    defaultMessage: 'Privacy Policy',
  },
});
```

Then, in the render function:

```
  const copy = formatMessage(messages.copy, {
    termsAndConditionsLink: <a href="#" className="u-underline text-color-grey">`${formatMessage(messages.termsAndConditions)}`</a>,
    returnPolicyLink: <a href="#" className="u-underline text-color-grey">`${formatMessage(messages.returnPolicy)}`</a>,
    privacyPolicyLink: <a href="#" className="u-underline text-color-grey">`${formatMessage(messages.privacyPolicy)}`</a>,
  });

return <div> { copy } </div>
```

This doesn't work. I get:
By clicking the "Place Order" button, you confirm that you have read, understood, and accept our [object Object], [object Object], and [object Object].

What is the correct way to accomplish this task?

Comment: It looks like as of now this is not supported. https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/137

Answer (score 13):

First, it depends on your react-intl version.
I've made it work using `react-intl v2.x` (2.8 to be exact). Here's how I did:

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  copy: {
    id: 'copy',
    defaultMessage: 'Accept our {TermsAndConditionsLink}',
  },
  termsAndConditions: {
    id: 'termsAndConditions',
    defaultMessage: 'Terms and conditions',
  },
  termsAndConditionsUrl: {
    id: 'termsAndConditionsUrl',
    defaultMessage: '/url',
  },
});

<FormattedMessage
  {...messages.copy}
  values={{
    TermsAndConditionsLink: (
      <a href={intl.formatMessage(messages.termsAndConditionsUrl)}>
        {intl.formatMessage(messages.termsAndConditions)}
      </a>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

---

For newer `react-intl` version, you can find your answer in the docs:

v3.x:
https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x#enhanced-formattedmessage--formatmessage-rich-text-formatting

v4.x:
https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#formatmessage

Comment: For reference, here's the latest doc after they moved everything out of github: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api#formatmessage

Answer (score 3):

```
<FormattedMessage 
        id="footer.table_no" 
        defaultMessage="Hello {link}" 
        values={{ link: <a href="www.google.com">World</a> }}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Can you use the `FormattedHTMLMessage` component?](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/src/components/html-message.js)

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  copy: {
    id: 'checkout.OrderReview.copy',
    description: 'Label for add card button',
    defaultMessage: 'By clicking the "Place Order" button, you confirm that you have read, understood, and accept our {termsAndConditionsLink}, {returnPolicyLink}, and {privacyPolicyLink}.',
  },
  termsAndConditions: {
    id: 'checkout.OrderReview.termsAndConditions',
    defaultMessage: '<a href="/url">Terms and Conditions</a>',
  },
});

const Component = () => <FormattedHTMLMessage {...{
  ...messages.copy,
  values: {
    termsAndConditionsLink: <FormattedHTMLMessage {...messages. termsAndConditions} />
  }
} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <FormattedMessage
    id="project.ai.aiTool.googTesting"
    defaultMessage="Google is reportedly testing an {aiTool} for journalists"
    values={{
      aiTool: (
        <a href="google.com/ai-tool">
          <FormattedMessage
            id="project.ai.aiTool"
            defaultMessage="AI tool"
          />
        </a>
      ),
    }}
  />
```